# ImageMagick convert script is failing to generate thumbnails

Tags: imagemagick

Product Information:

ImageMagick Vers : ImageMagick-6.8.6

Operating System : RHEL 6.4.

We are using ImageMagick in our CMS application to convert eps files to png files. But the script is not able generate thumbnails while converting. Our application is running on a Linux system.

When we run the `identify` command on one such file, we get the following:

```
# identify tmp/ADVAIR_DISKUS_250.eps
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `tmp/ADVAIR_DISKUS_250.eps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552
```

Can some one suggest how to address this issue?

Comment: Would you elaborate?  Imagmagick convert is great at producing thumbnails.

Comment: We have integrated imagemagic tool to our CMS application i.e Adobe CQ.This conversion is done part of workflow.When we are uploading any eps file which coverts the eps file to png file.Coversion is happening but not able to view the thumbnail for the converted eps file. Our application is running on linux operating system.And also we have tested the same in windows operating system ,it's working fine.When we run command-identify tmp/ADVAIR_DISKUS_250.eps 
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `tmp/ADVAIR_DISKUS_250.eps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a proprietary CMS.

Comment: @jasonwryan I disagree. The origin of the issue may be proprietary software, but the output he provided is the result of a regular imagemagic command (`identify`).

Comment: @user52746 its best to put additional info in the question itself. It's easier to find and read. I've gone ahead and edited your question for you.

Comment: @Patrick OP's organization obviously paid a lot of money for their CMS: they can recoup some of that investment by using Adobe's support, not the good will of the FLOSS community.

Comment: There is at least someone else with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779050/imagemagick-fails-to-identify-eps-files-no-decode-delegate So it seems to be a bug in imagemagick.

Comment: @jasonwryan except this is a question about imagemagick, which can pertain to **any** use of imagemagick, not just with the CMS. Thus the answer will benefit the community. Are you saying we shouldn't support anyone with RedHat because they have RedHat support? If the question had been "Why do I get this error when using `identify`?" and didn't mention the CMS at all, would you still refuse to help?

Comment: @Patrick Comparing Adobe with Redhat is disingenuous; one supports FLOSS (and FLOSS developers), the other replaces it (and them). So, yes, I would refuse to help.

Answer (score 1):

The following commandline should do the job:

```
convert -thumbnail 200x200 test.eps test.png
```

Check the folders, if you are allowed to write into.

Comment: this issue is occurring for some of the eps file but not all.And also we are able to covert and see the thumbnails using the command covert test.eps test.png. Could you please tell what is the difference in usage of this command?

Comment: This command creates a thumbnail of a certain size (200 x 200 in my example). Like **@cjm** I think, that you have some EPS-files, that can't be read by **convert**. Think about using **ps2ps** (if you are on a Linux system). It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick depends on [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to read EPS images.  The error "no decode delegate for this image format" suggests you don't have Ghostscript installed on your Linux system, or your ImageMagick was built without Ghostscript support for some reason.

Comment: Actually we are not seeing this for all the eps files for some of them only this issue we are seeing.And also we have tried the same in windows and it's working without any issue.And also, can we install ghost script separately in our linux environment and then imagicMagick work without any problem?

Comment: @user52746 there are multiple types of eps files (eps, eps2, eps3, epsf, epsi, ...). Likely its failing for some and not others because they're different types of eps files, and your ghostscript doesn't know how to process some of those types.